# Assigning to undeclared variable

Tags: coffeescript

Please, consider the following code. If I declare the `exports` field as follows:

```
exports = 
  someFunc : -> # blablabla
  someOtherFunc : ->
```

It gets compiled into:

```
var exports;

exports = {
  someFunc: function() {},
  someOtherFunc: function() {}
};
```

But as you probably already know I need the exports field to remain undeclared. In other words I need to somehow inform the compiler not to produce the `var exports;` statement.
I know that I can hack around this like that:

```
exports.someFunc = ->
exports.someOtherFunc = ->
```

but that's just messy and very much seems like a defect, since the essence of CoffeeScript is to reduce the code noise.

Is there a way or a better hack around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of one a bit more clever hack around this, which by accident suits the `export` needs much better, since it doesn't erase the previously assigned export fields:

```
exports[k] = v for k, v of {
  someFunc : ->
  someOtherFunc : ->
}
```

But still it's a hack and it only works for assigning the fields of undeclared objects. How to assign the undeclared variable remains a question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can assign directly to exports (in nodejs). I think your code should be

```
module.exports = 
  someFunc : -> # blablabla
  someOtherFunc : ->
```

in which case CS will assume module is already defined and will simply output

```
module.exports = {
  someFunc: function() {},
  someOtherFunc: function() {}
};
```

Comment: This is correct. `exports` is a variable with module-wide scope that acts as a reference to `module.exports`. Writing `exports = ...` won't affect `module.exports`. It's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you "need the exports field to remain undeclared" because you're writing a Node.js module `exports` is already declared, yes? In that case this question and its top answer ought to go a long way toward helping you: [How do I define global variables in CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables)

In short you'll do something like this:

```
root = exports ? this

root = 
  someFunc      : -> # blablabla
  someOtherFunc : ->
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link, but your suggestion is wrong since you simply reassign the `root` value in the second statement. I.e., first you assign `root` to `exports ? this`, then you reassign it to the object with the functions.