# Backbone jasmine sinon.stub typeError

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine, sprockets, sinon

I'm trying to write a simple spec for a Backbone Todos collection which stubs the Backbone Todo model.

Here's my spec:

```
describe "TodoApp.Collections.Todos", ->

  beforeEach ->
    @todoStub = sinon.stub window, 'TodoApp.Models.Todo'

  afterEach ->
    @todoStub.restore()
```

This gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property TodoApp.Models.Todo as function
```

The Todo model is defined though as todo = new TodoApp.Models.Todo() doens't give an error.

Is it a scoping issue? Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ran into that problem too. You should call it like this...

```
    beforeEach ->
            @todoStub = sinon.stub window.TodoApp.Models, 'Todo'
```

instead of this.

```
    beforeEach ->
            @todoStub = sinon.stub window, 'TodoApp.Models.Todo'
```

this solved the problem for me

@smek: this also solves your problem from http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/25/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-2.html

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're using `sinon.stub window, 'TodoApp.Models.Todo'` would be for wrapping `window['TodoApp.Models.Todo']` as a function. http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs

With sinon you're more likely going to be wrapping a particular function on your Todo model with a stub: `sinon.stub TodoApp.Models.Todo, 'Foo'`.

Sinon can [stub an entire object](http://cjohansen.no/en/javascript/test_spies_stubs_and_mocks_part_1_5) but I think it's designed to be more granular.

Comment: Hi Erick, thanks for your answer. I'm trying to stub the todo model so I can test the todos collection in isolation. I'm following the example on http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/25/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-2.html where is states you can stub the models constructor function like this.

Comment: @smek have you attached your ```Todo``` model to ```window```, similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables ?

Comment: @Erick I've defined my model with: class window.TodoApp.Models.Todo extends Backbone.Model

Comment: @EricBock I have a similar requirement to stub an entire BackBone Model object using SinonJS. The link ( stub an entire object ) which you posted doesnt seem to work. Is there any other example link for the same,
I tried the http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/25/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-2.html  tutorial, but getting errors like "Attempted to wrap undefined property Todo as function"