# How to make a JS object available across multiple files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, file, scope, coffeescript

I'm a js noob working on a Rails app. I defined a useful JS function in one of my javascript files, and I'd like it to be available to call in other files. However, it's not. Here's a simplified example of my situation... note that I'm using CoffeeScript (but AFAIK that should make no difference):

```
#file: app/assets/javascripts/foos.js.coffee
testFoo: ->
  alert 'Foo'

#file: app/assets/javascripts/bars.js.coffee
jQuery ->
  testFoo()
```

This doesn't work, and in the console I get: `testFoo is not defined`.

Both files are included in the page, if I put an alert or console log in either one the page responds as expected. I feel like I must be overlooking something brutally obvious here... what is it?

Comment: When you say "both are included on the page" do you mean you have two script elements in your HTML?  If so check the ordering and the spelling, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoffeeScript & Global Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables)

Comment: @RayToal: CoffeeScript wraps everything in `(function() { ... })()` wrappers to prevent polluting the global namespace.

Comment: See the following Thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short try this :

```
root = exports ? this
root.foo = -> alert 'Foo'
```