# Calling functions defined with coffee script?

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript

I have the following coffeescript code to generate and alert box:

```
show_alert = () ->
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!")
```

which compiles to:

```
(function() {
  var show_alert;

  show_alert = function() {
    return alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
  };

}).call(this);
```

in my html I have the following

```
<input onclick='show_alert()' type='button' value='Show alert box' />
```

However, no alert box shows?  The following is the html copied from the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Rails Application</title>
    <style type='text/css'>.application h1 {
  color: lime; }
</style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>(function() {
  var show_alert;

  show_alert = function() {
    return alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
  };

}).call(this);
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello from applicaiton.html.haml</h1>
    <div class='application'><h1>Hello World</h1>
<input onclick='show_alert()' type='button' value='Show alert box' />
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why am I not able to get an alert box to show up?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your problem is that the generated javascript code is in another scope. You have to solve this 
by either adding the `-b` parameter to the coffeescript compiler or export your function 
explicitly via

```
root = exports ? this
root.show_alert = () -> alert("Hello! I am an alert box!")
```

For more information about the exporting and scope issue have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215132/832273

I created a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tV97u/2/) with the above coffeescript code

Answer (score 11):

I found two ways to solve this issue
FIRST add @ before function name

```
@say_hi = () ->
  $(alert('Hello!!!'))
```

SECOND at the end of coffee file add

```
window["say_hi"] = say_hi
```

Answer (score 4):

in your coffeescrpt code, try to save the function to window: `window["show_alert"] = show_alert`

Comment: jftr i think `root = exports ? this; root.show_alert = show_alert` is better instead of directly accessing window. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4215132/832273 for details

Comment: @mru javascript is always extremely confusing to me.  Is there a specific reference site or text either of you would recommend?

Comment: @KurtRudolph depends on what you are looking for but have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript