# global variable in node using coffeescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

I checked this [How do I define global variables in CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables)
 for declaring a global variable i.e., declaring in the app.js and accessing in the routes/index.coffee

I declared (exports ? this).db = redis.createClient() in the app.coffee and tried to access the db in the routes.index.coffee using db.set('online',Date.now(), (err,reply) -> console.log(reply.toString()) ) this doesn't seem to work...what is happening..I am on node 0.8.9

There are other approaches in which it works but curious to know what is happening...
Also tried the @db = redis.createClient() in the app.coffee which doesn't work either

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exports` doesn't define "*globals*;" it defines "*public*" members of a module available via `require`. Also, `exports` is always initially defined and `exports === this`, so `(exports ? this)` isn't actually doing anything.

However, since globals are generally frowned upon (and do defeat some of the intents of Node's module system), a common approach for web applications is to define a custom middleware allowing access to the `db` as a property of the `req` or `res` objects:

```
# app.coffee
app.use (req, res, next) ->
  req.db = redis.createClient()
  next()
```

```
# routes/index.coffee
exports.index = (req, res) ->
  req.db.set('online', Date.now(), (err,reply) -> console.log(reply))
```

An example of this can be found in [`decorate.js`](https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www/blob/c54bac79fd99403ae1341eec98a05fb703eac13b/decorate.js#L57-185) of [`npm-www`](https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www), the repository behind [npmjs.org](https://npmjs.org/):

```
function decorate (req, res, config) {
  //...

  req.model = res.model = new MC

  // ...

  req.cookies = res.cookies = new Cookies(req, res, config.keys)
  req.session = res.session = new RedSess(req, res)

  // ...

  req.couch = CouchLogin(config.registryCouch).decorate(req, res)

  // ...
}
```

Though, if you'd still rather define `db` as a global instead, Node.JS defines a `global` variable you can attach to:

```
global.db = redis.createClient()
```

Comment: thanks. I knew about the global object. But I was trying to understand why it was n't working when it seemed that it was working for everybody.