# CoffeeScript function can not be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails 3.2.8 application that I have recently upgraded from 3.1, and I have converted all of the original `application.js` code to CoffeeScript. Most of it is working fine. However, I have a breadcrumb function that I call in several views that is not being found. For right now, I'm just throwing up an alert to see if it is working:

```
product_breadcrumb = (attr) ->
  alert attr
```

That's in a file called `product_search.js.coffee`. It is being successfully compiled, and ends up looking like this:

```
(function() {
  var product_breadcrumb;
  product_breadcrumb = function(attr) {
    return alert(attr);
  };
}).call(this);
```

I guess that's right, I don't know. Anyway, in Firebug I'm getting:

```
ReferenceError: product_breadcrumb is not defined
```

Please note that this is after an Ajax call. I don't know why the function wouldn't be available though. It's just a function definition after all. Shouldn't it still be available to the rendered HTML from the Ajax call? I can't understand why the function can't be found.

Comment: If you type `product_breadcrumb` or `product_breadcrumb("foo")` into the console, does it return a value?

Comment: Also, you seem to have a parenthesis mismatch in the compiled JS that you pasted, which may or may not be significant. What is the parenthesis in `}).call` attached to?

Comment: Thanks Jason, cut and paste error. fixed.

Comment: And what about the console question?

Comment: @JasonSwett this is just a namespace issue, that's why he's getting reference error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be on the global scope, and then you need to call it that way.

You should write:

```
root = exports ? this
```

and name your function

```
root.product_breadcrumb
```

then you can call it elsewhere as expected.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215132/417872) for a much lengthier explanation.