# CoffeeScript and Rails: Setting and getting global variables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Just getting to the CoffeeScript part of my first rails app; never did any JS/CoffeeScript before, so lots of questions. Starting with:

In my app, users can "claim" (take ownership of) tasks (or ideas, as I call them). Each user may have up to 3 ideas at any given time. So:

1) My current code looks like this:

```
$ ->
  exports = this
  exports.claimedCount = 0
  $('.claim').bind 'ajax:success', ->
    $(this).text("Claimed")
    $(this).addClass("btn-success")
    claimedCount++
    alert(claimedCount)
```

What this is *supposed* to do is declare a global var `claimedCount` and increment it every time the user claims an idea. What is *actually* does is nothing: `Uncaught ReferenceError: claimedCount is not defined`

Why is that? How should I really define the variable? Do I even need a global variable for what I'm trying to do? (Each idea has its own Claim button).

2) The user might render the page when they already have a few ideas claimed. Thus, I need to set the `claimedCount` using Rails when first rendering the page. Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated (should I rename my `.js.coffee` file to `.js.coffee.erb` and do it there? What's the usual spot for js init code like this?)

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Every bit of javascript should be scoped to the minimum related DOM elements. I guess I should open source the in house js 'framework' I use

Comment: Of course I should scope vars in the most limited way I can. That's my question: How limited can I make them, and how? Do I need global vars? If not, what do I need then?

Comment: Basically, create a namespace: `YourAppName`. Then for each page you could have a namespace included in the app's one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Khaled's answer on the first question.

On the second one, I would rather rename the file to **.js.coffee.erb** so that it is preprocessed with erb first and write something like :

```
window.claimedCount = <%= @user.claims.count %>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that on production your assets are precompiled, so the claims count won't update (unless you recompile your assets). `.js.coffee.erb` is almost never a good idea

Answer (score 2):

If you take your code to [js2coffee.com](http://js2coffee.org/) and convert it to js you will see that your variable is not global because it is inside the function.

You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables) on how to declare global variables in coffee script (mainly you use `window.myvariable` )

About the second question, you could put the value in a hidden field in your html and then grab it using jquery selectors.

`<input type="hidden" id="claimsCount" value=<%= @user.claims.count %>>`

then in your js

`$('#claimsCount').val()`