# Javascript scopes in coffeescript for Google Analytics Code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, coffeescript, google-analytics-api

The codes for Google Analytics use a global `_gaq` object for the analytics commands. They advise to check if such an object already exists, like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
// Command
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

In CoffeeScript, this would look like this:

```
_gaq = _gaq or []
```

Which compiles to this:

```
(function() {
    var _gaq;
    _gaq = _gaq || [];
}).call(this);
```

How can I write a CoffeeScript code that will lead to the behaviour of the above Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the `_gaq` variable available in the **global scope** you could write this in coffeescript:

```
_gaq = window._gaq ?= []
```

The javascript output:

```
var _gaq, _ref;
_gaq = (_ref = window._gaq) != null ? _ref : window._gaq = [];
```

This way you can latter call `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables) in stackoverflow that talks about global variables in coffeescript that you might want to check.

Comment: Like the other, it would still add `var _gaq` to the list of variables at the top of the scope, throwing out the `_gaq` that is already there.

Comment: Check my edit please, as I thing I could be leading you in a error with the first code example.

Comment: And one more edit, sorry to messup on the answer so much, much but I was not happy with it. This way you can still have _gaq as a private variable if you need so, and at the same time it will get the value of a possible defined _gaq object declared on the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally assign a value to a variable iff it doesn't exist elegantly like this:

```
window._gaq ?= []
```

There are two tricky things going on here:

1. Note that I'm referencing `window._gaq`.  The Google Analytics JavaScript attaches the `_gaq` object directly on the `window` object.  For more info, see: http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope
2. Observe the `?=` operator.  This is CoffeeScript's existential operator, which provides for safer conditional assignment than `||=`.  For more info, Google for "CoffeeScript existential operator".  (I'd link you directly, but I can't post another link, because I don't have enough reputation points yet.)

Finally, I've put together a gist that I use for Google Analytics tracking in CoffeeScript here: https://gist.github.com/brainix/4394158

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
_gaq?.push ['_code']
```

Which will compile to:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.2
(function() {
  if (typeof _gaq !== "undefined" && _gaq !== null) {
    _gaq.push(['_code']);
  }

}).call(this);
```

Comment: But it would still add `var _gaq` to the top of the scope.

Comment: @LambdaDusk No it doesn't! At least when I compile the code from above to a JavaScript file.

Comment: But I still need to initialize the `_gaq` with `var _gaq = _gaq || []`. If I used yours, all the commands would be swallowed if the `_gaq` wasn't already there.

Comment: Okay, then I misunderstund you question or you weren't totally clear. As long as you just want to push the code to the `_gag` object if it exists then the code above should be fine. What should happen if `_gag` does not exist?

Comment: It should be initialized with `[]`.