# How can I access CoffeeScript to JS compiled vars in the Chrome Developer Tools JavaScript Console?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Rails app with a CoffeeScript file. The Rails Asset Pipeline compiles it into a JavaScript file.

I'd like to open up the Chrome Developer Tools JavaScript Console and execute functions defined in my `.coffee` file.

However in the compiled JS it's all wrapped up like this...

```
(function() {

  var youLot = function() {
    return "Wot?";
  };

}).call(this);
```

So what happens in the JS console...

```
youLot();
ReferenceError: youLot is not defined
```

Without going through too many contortions, is there a way I can call `youLot()` in the Chrome JS console even though I originally declared it in a CoffeeScript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
window.myVariable
```

But, I recommend you read up on coffee scripts handling of scope.
[SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables)