# Coffeescript to javascript transpiling Inaccuracy

Tags: coffeescript

I don't know if this is IDE related, or purely about the transpiling process.
I use Webstorm on a mac, and have node,npm and coffeescript installed. The IDE is using that to make the transpiling to javascript:

```
//Coffeescript code, simple variable declaration
myamount = 56

//Traspiled javascript generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  var myamount;
  myamount = 5;
}).call(this);
```

Any clue why it puts the variable in anonymous function ? This is not correct transpiling.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is to prevent you from polluting the global namespace.

As explained in the documentation - [lexical scope and variable safety](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope):

> all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function: 
>   (function(){ ... })(); This safety wrapper, combined with the
>   automatic generation of the var keyword, make it exceedingly difficult
>   to pollute the global namespace by accident.