# Shared JS (Coffee) in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

If I want to share some JavaScript function between different files under *app/assets/javascript* what would be the best way to I organise the directory structure?

Let's say I have *shared.js.coffee*

```
sharedFunction = ->
  'Hello '
```

Now, how can I use it in some other place? Like here, in *welcome.js.coffee*

```
welcome = (name) ->
  sharedFunction() + name
```

How can I make *shared.js.cofee* **always be loaded first**?

I tried to put it in the very beginning of *application.js*, but it doesn't change anything. Seems *shared* file loading too long, and *welcome* manages to start executing and notice that sharedFunction is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `application.js`, load shared first:

```
//= require shared
//rest of code
```

and in shared, if its that necessary, make your variable accessible globally:

```
@sharedFunction = ->
  'Hello '
```

Notice its a bad practice too have such global variables, at least try to keep them in namespaces.

Comment: That global variable tag made the trick! So it seems for me that each js.coffee file comes separated from the others. Put sharedFunction into a regular .js file also works. I'm confused.

Comment: yes, its the basics of coffeescript, each file is wrapped in a function. You have to explictly tell what should be accessible globally

Comment: can I make use of sharedFunction out of this wrapper function without making it global variable?

Comment: using //require could do the trick, but having a tooolset within a global namespace is ok

Answer (score 7):

I do it in this way:

- Ensure you require the file in application.js before anything else, expecially before `require_tree`
- Export the functions (in my case a class, so it's namespaced)

Example: (Suppose we have application.js and shared.js.coffee at same level)

**application.js**

```
//= require ./shared
//= require_tree .
```

**shared.js.coffee**

```
class MyNamespace
  @mySharedFunc: () ->
    doSomething()

root             = exports ? this
root.MyNamespace = MyNamespace
```

You can now easily access in your other coffeescript files the function by referencing it in this way `MyNamespace.mySharedFunc()`

**P.S.**

The misterious thing about exports is explained very well in this stackoverflow question: [How do I define global variables in CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables)

Comment: what the last two lines do exactly? I just on studying Coffee namespaces and saw the following way of defining a namespace *window.MyNamespace = {}*. Is that the same thing here?

Comment: As I typed in the **P.S.**, read this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables

Answer (score 0):

Basically functions loaded earlier can be used later. But in this case the reason your function not working is very simple: You forget to execute it.

Simply replace

```
sharedFunction + name
```

With

```
sharedFunction() + name
```

And it's done.

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake in the example but not the real problem. Thanks anyway you noticed that :)

Answer (score -1):

Best would be to only ever include one JS file. You can split it between different assets if your asset pipeline knows how to paste them together, but it is inferior to send different JavaScript to different pages. It seems counterintuitive to send a bigger file, especially for every page, but caching turns this on its head: your JS file should only be loaded once. This also automatically means you will have access to all your functions from any of your pages.