# django-coffeescript converting script with jquery call(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, coffeescript

I'm using django-coffeescript in my project. But there is some with conversion.

In my hello.coffee file:

```
hello = ()->
  console.log 'Hello'
```

But it converts to:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
   var hello;

   hello = function() {
     return console.log('hello');
   };

}).call(this);
```

I want:

```
var hello = function() {
  return console.log('hello');
}
```

Comment: What affordances are there for you to compile without the closure wrapper? @mariodev mentions the -b flag, which will compile the coffeescript as "bare". (http://coffeescript.org/#usage)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoffeeScript & Global Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can override `COFFEESCRIPT_EXECUTABLE` in your `settings.py` like so:

```
COFFEESCRIPT_EXECUTABLE = 'coffee -b'
```