# CoffeeScript working strangely with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I cannot get *CoffeeScript* working with *Rails*. This is the first time I'm using CoffeeScript and I'm also fairly new with *Rails* too, so I don't know how to make this simple CoffeeScript function to work in the right way. Below is my **people.js.coffee** file at **app/assets/javascript** directory.

```
myFunction = ->
alert "test"
```

The alert *“test”* message **only shows up when I load the page** (app/views/people.html.erb and _form.html.erb partial); **not when I click the below button** in the form:

```
<%= submit_tag "Test CoffeeScript", :type => 'button', 
:id => 'coffeeScript', :onclick => 'myFunction()' %>
```

I don't know why this strange behaviour is happening. Why **:onclick** is not working? The generated source code for the button should be ok:

```
  <input id="coffeeScript" name="commit" onclick="myFunction()" 
type="button" value="Test CoffeeScript" />
```

Below is my **application.js** file  at **app/assets/javascript**.

```
...
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

My Ruby version is 2.1.0
Here are some values when I ran bundle show command:

- coffee-rails (4.0.1)
- coffee-script (2.2.0)
- coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
- jbuilder (1.5.3)
- jquery-rails (3.1.0)
- rails (4.0.2)
- railties (4.0.2)
- sass (3.2.19)
- sass-rails (4.0.3)
- sprockets (2.11.0)
- sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
- turbolinks (2.2.2)

My JavaScript files are working ok; I tried similar type of function in JavaScript and it was ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the function is in another scope. You can do it either with unobtrusive jquery.

```
$ ->
  myFunction = ->
    alert("test")

  $("#coffeeScript").on "click", ->
    myFunction()
```

And remove the onclick handler from

```
<%= submit_tag "Test CoffeeScript", type: 'button', id: 'coffeeScript' %>
```

or...

```
root = exports ? this
root.myFunction = () -> alert("test!")
```

I'd recommend the first one, but that is just my opinion though. Also, you have to be very careful about indentation in CoffeeScript, it works a lot like Python, whitespace matters.

An explanation on scopes and js/coffee is here [How do I define global variables in CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables/4215132#4215132)