# Coffeescript Uncaught Reference

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm following the first steps of the rails guide http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript

The index.html.erb looks like  
    `<a href="#" onclick="paintIt(this, '#990000')">Paint it red</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="paintIt(this, '#009900', '#FFFFFF')">Paint it green</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="paintIt(this, '#000099', '#FFFFFF')">Paint it blue</a>`

I added coffeescript under app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js.coffee

    `paintIt = (element, backgroundColor, textColor) ->
         element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
         if textColor?
             element.style.color = textColor`

I get this error:

    `Uncaught ReferenceError: paintIt is not defined`

I tried chancing `paintIt` to `@paintIt` and `window.paintIt` to no avail. I have a temporary fix of just using plain old javascript in app/assets/javascripts/applications.js, but I wanted to begin using coffeescript. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add `paintIt` to the global namespace.  See here for good explanation on how to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to add `paintIt` to the global namespace. See here for good explanation on how to: [stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4214731/822138)

Via @vee. Copied here so this question can be closed.