# How to access a variable across CoffeeScript functions?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, global-variables

I use CS in Rails. If I have:

```
foo = ->
  ...

bar = ->
  ...

-> 
  someCount = 123
  foo()
  bar()
```

How can I access `someCount` inside `foo()` and `bar()` without passing it directly as an argument?

I thought that this would require declaring `someCount` as a global variable. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables) and [this](https://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/02_syntax.html), but I don't understand how to implement it. I tried:

```
root = exports ? this
root.someCount = 123
```

but then inside `foo()` I couldn't access it by either `someCount` (*someCount is not defined*) or `root.someCount`(*root is not defined*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to declare `somecount` in a scope that the other functions are also in:

```
somecount = null

foo = ->
  alert somecount

bar = ->
  alert somecount

-> 
  someCount = 123
  foo()
  bar()
```

Comment: I feel embarrassed :)