# How to build .coffee into .js without variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, compilation, coffeescript

How can I compile coffee to js without add `var foo, bar, baz` ? with this exemple code :

```
foo = 42
bar = foo + 2
baz = bar + 3
```

coffee -c give

alert "Hello CoffeeScript!"

```
var bar, baz, foo;

foo = 42;

bar = foo + 2;

baz = bar + 3;
```

How can I ignore variables déclarations ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you purposely want those three variables to be global?

Comment: Yes, my script works if there is no "var" (I delete it at hand to test), but not works when there is declaration ;)

Comment: @muistooshort this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/how-do-i-define-global-variables-in-coffeescript) don't resolved my problem... May be it's impossible to remove declaration in coffee?

Comment: If you want to remove the `var`s then you want global variables, the duplicate covers globals.

Comment: it's more complicate : I can't add global.foo for foo var because the code is used on client side too, and in my case, It's forbidden to modify client code.