# How to spread out CoffeeScript over several files so variables are shared?

Tags: coffeescript, code-organization

Say I have the most basic CoffeeScript program possible that goes like:

```
console.log "Hello, World!"
```

But it's too complicated so I want to separate my program into multiple files.

```
#hello.coffee
console.log "Hello, #{stuff}!"
```

And

```
#stuff.coffee
stuff = "World"
```

What should be done to `hello.coffee` to know the variable `stuff`?

The catch of it is that I'd rather not have to do separate compiles to JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I define global variables in CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/how-do-i-define-global-variables-in-coffeescript)

Comment: So I can just add things to `window` like `window.stuff = "World"` and this will be available in another file like: `stuff = window.stuff`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it will be available in all files on the global `window` object. But there is no need for `stuff= window.stuff`. You can just use `stuff` in another file (ie. `window.stuff` is the same as `stuff` given that there isn't another local `stuff` variable defined).

Comment: Great, that should solve it. Thanks.